# SQL: Rank / Group a Column by Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, grouping, rank

Using SQL Server Management Studio v17.9.1

I'm trying to rank / order / group some data by Site and Area by Date, but I'm struggling to get my head around not ranking the area alphabetically and ranking it by the earliest date it appears.

Here's the data I have:

```
Site   |   Area   |   Space   |   Date
DCG        X          7           02/02/2020 12:13
DCG        X          5           04/02/2020 11:47
DCG        X          12          10/02/2020 15:14
GNL        U          0           03/03/2020 18:35
GNL        A          4           04/03/2020 08:28
GNL        C          4           06/03/2020 09:07
GNL        B          1           16/03/2020 07:10
DPL        U          0           18/03/2020 09:28
DPL        A          1           18/03/2020 09:36
DPL        A          1           20/03/2020 20:04
SGR        F          2           21/03/2020 19:42
SGR        B          2           22/03/2020 10:30
SGR        C          3           24/03/2020 08:17
SGR        F          1           01/04/2020 09:00
SGR        E          1           02/02/2020 10:57
SGR        F          1           02/02/2020 15:50
```

I want to add 2 columns that rank / group the site and the area in ascending order of date, like so:

```
Site   |   Area   |   Space   |   Date              |   Site Order   |   Area Order   |
DCG        X          7           02/02/2020 12:13         1                 1
DCG        X          5           04/02/2020 11:47         1                 1
DCG        X          12          10/02/2020 15:14         1                 1
GNL        U          0           03/03/2020 18:35         2                 1
GNL        A          4           04/03/2020 08:28         2                 2
GNL        C          4           06/03/2020 09:07         2                 3 
GNL        B          1           16/03/2020 07:10         2                 4
DPL        U          0           18/03/2020 09:28         3                 1
DPL        A          1           18/03/2020 09:36         3                 2 
DPL        A          1           20/03/2020 20:04         3                 2
SGR        F          2           21/03/2020 19:42         4                 1
SGR        B          2           22/03/2020 10:30         4                 2
SGR        C          3           24/03/2020 08:17         4                 3
SGR        F          1           01/04/2020 09:00         4                 1
SGR        E          1           02/02/2020 10:57         4                 4
SGR        F          1           02/02/2020 15:50         4                 1
```

Apologies if I've not made it clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `min()` as a window function to get the minimum date for each site and site/area combo.  Then use `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (order by min_site_date, site) as site_seqnum,
       dense_rank() over (partition by site order by min_site_date) as area_seqnum
from (select t.*,
             min(date) over (partition by site) as min_site_date,
             min(date) over (partition by site, area) as min_site_area_date
      from t
     ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function :

```
select t.*, 
       dense_rank() over (order by site, site_date) as site_sequence,
       dense_rank() over (partition by site order by area, site_area_date) as area_sequence
from (select t.*,
            min([date]) over (partition by [site]) as site_date,
            min([date]) over (partition by [site], area) as site_area_date
      from table t
     ) t;
```